# Import list from one groovy file to another

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have two groovy files.

First.groovy:

```
class First {

    def getContent() {
        content = ["one", "two"]
    }
}

return this
```

And second.groovy:

```
{
    node(label) {

        def listClass = this.class.classLoader.parseClass("First.groovy")
        def CONTENT=listClass.getContent()
}
```

I get error from jenkins when I run the job:

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Class.getContent() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

kindly advice on efficient way to import a list from one groovy file to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins offers the method [load(filepath)](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script) for your case so you don't have to juggle with all the classloader methods.

You don't necessarely need the `class` in your `First.groovy` so simply remove it.

**First.groovy**

```
def getContent() {
    def content = ["one", "two"]
    return content
}

return this;
```

And call it like:

```
def first = load 'First.groovy'
def content = first.getContent()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
After utilizing the one you have posted, I am getting the below error:

`hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@23856748]
Possible solutions: tail(), tail(), wait(), last(), last(), any() `

Kindly advice

Comment: What did you execute? Looks like you are calling the list that is returned

Comment: Yes, I am utilizing the content as below:

`stage("Build services") {

            parallel content { CONTENT_NAME ->
                [CONTENT_NAME, {
                    //iterate through each job
                    try {
                        some code;
                        }
                    catch (err) {
                        echo err.toString()
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                        throw err
                    }
                }]
            }`

Comment: This seems a bit out of scope for this question. Maybe open a new one as this one seems to be answered.

Comment: Sure, Micheal, Will do rightaway
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67220595/utilize-list-from-another-groovy-file