# How to parelelly execute a list imported from another Groovy file?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, import, jenkins-pipeline

I am importing a list from another groovy file and Utilizing it to iterate through the content:

First.groovy

```
def getContent() {
    def content = ["one", "two"]
    return content
}

return this;
```

And calling it like:

```
def first = load 'First.groovy'
def content = first.getContent()

stage("Build services") {
              parallel content { CONTENT_NAME ->
                 [CONTENT_NAME, {
                     //iterate through each job
                     try { 
                        some code;  
                       } 
                    catch (err) {
                         echo err.toString()
                         currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                         throw err
                     }
                 }]
             }
```

But I am getting error -

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: 
[org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@23856748]
Possible solutions: tail(), tail(), wait(), last(), last(), any()
```

Any clue on resolving this?

Comment: You are getting list correctly. But using it in a wrong way. This line throws exception `content { CONTENT_NAME `

Comment: Can you please advice what’s the right way of using it so that I can iterate through the list in parallel not sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> parallel: Execute in parallel Takes a map from branch names to
> closures

You need to create a map first and then execute it per [parallel](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/). Your `content` is only a List.

I would suggest a different approach on how to build the tasks:

```
def parallelTasks = [:]
for (element in content) {
    parallelTasks["${element}"] = {
      echo "${element}"
  }
}
parallel parallelTasks
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Micheal-Kemmerzell. I completely agree that we need to convert from the list to the map first.
After applying the code, I am getting below error:
`hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@3eb3fbd5]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), take(int), max(groovy.lang.Closure)`

The code is similar as the initial question.

Comment: Used collectentries to get content

`parallel parallelTasks.collectentries { CONTENT_NAME ->
                 [CONTENT_NAME, {`

Comment: I thank you both @michael-kemmerzell and daggett for helping me in resolving the issue.